# How to get address balance after particular block was issued

Tags: solidity, addresses, balances, blocks

How to get address balance if you know the block number?
In solidity you can call `address.balance`, but without specifying particular block.
Is there a way to do this in solidity or only py/js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to get the balance of a particular address at a given block number, which you can't do in Solidity. If this were the case, it would make any  non-full-sync mode impossible as verifying blocks would require access to the state at any arbitrary block in the past, which geth --fast wouldn't be able to do. Verifying blocks on full nodes would also be a lot more intensive due to the arbitrary block state access.

Answer (score 2):

As @flygoing points out, you cannot get a historical balance in Solidity, but you can get that value off-chain if you're running a full archive node (or have access to a full archive node through the RPC). The RPC's [`eth_getBalance`](https://github.com/paritytech/parity/wiki/JSONRPC-eth-module#eth_getbalance) takes a block argument. If you don't have a full archive node, your only recourse is to build the balance from the transactions which is not easy in a decentralized way (but is not too hard using the fully-centralized Etherscan).

Answer (score 0):

On this, you can do checkpoints in Solidity (save a state and then query from that state at a block number):

Here's an example: https://github.com/Giveth/minime/blob/master/contracts/MiniMeToken.sol